# Redis used_memory_rss is more than the config set 'maxmemory'?

Tags: linux, redis, memory-fragmentation

We have Set 120 GB Max Memory in Redis Server.

So in info output used_memory is always less than equal to 120GB but used_memory_rss is ~140GB

Can Someone Please explain the reason of this?

Comment: That's because the memory gets fragmented during runtime.

Comment: But Why it is more than 120. OS Should not give more memory to Redis Process defined in 'maxmemory' . If it try to give, OS itself can go OOM.

Comment: I just want to understand why it is more than defined parameter 'maxmemory'. 
In my understanding Redis should not use memory more than 'maxmemory', because we have already given 95% of the total RAM to Redis Process.

Answer (score 4):

Total used memory includes any memory Redis has used outside of data storage, in particular various buffers and memory used during disk persistence operations such as `BGSAVE` and AOF rewrites. The `maxmemory` setting is for the amount of *data* allowed (and includes some buffers such as client buffers) - not total system memory.

When you reach `maxmemory` Redis will stop allowing added memory usage through data commands. But it is still free to use memory outside of that to handle it's other duties.